# Netty Problem in Java Project with GRPC and GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish, netty, guava, grpc

I have a project with

- Glassfish
- Java 8
- GRPC

I have an error on client side.

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 9090)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
```

while this code is running, there is an exception like below :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder
at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:37)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:23)
at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)    
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I solve this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError is generally caused by a previous failure. Check your logs looking for an Error before that one; it'll have more information.

Comment: How can ı solve the classpath problem?

Comment: You've not provided the underlying error message yet. Without it there isn't enough information to know what is wrong.

Comment: I added all error.

Comment: It still does not include the triggering error. There is either a causal chain ("caused by") or an earlier error that is the true source and has the information about what is wrong.

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

use `-verbose:class` java option to log the root ClassLoader error/exception occurring - I've found that by default this information isn't logged for some reason. For example I had this same issue and it turned out to be a guava version issue:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V
```

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder
```

does not say which class definition not found which caused NettyChannelBuilder to fail to initialize. Most likely the netty classes are missing (`io.netty:netty-*`)? Have you disabled transitive dependencies by any chance?

Comment: There is a classpath problem.